# Resetting animation in Android without starting it

Tags: android

I have an `AnimationDrawable` that is running. How to stop & reset it so that it does not start again until `start()` is called? Calling `setVisible(true, true)` resets it, but also immediately starts animation, and I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the animation to occur once use:

```
android:repeatCount="0"
```

but if you're trying to animate and then not animate, you'll probably have to use 2 different animations.  More information would be nice :D